# SOAP UI - Is it possible to capture json response value and pass it as a parameter to another test case?

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

I have below json output from REST API, i want to capture the id (from response) and pass it as a parameter to another test. Is it possible?

```
{
   "Documents": "1",
   "maxResults": "1000",
   "pageSize": "1",
   "startIndex": "0",
   "documents": [   {
      "id": "sdfg7234-shdjfh823-wjk283-sdjf29",
      "name": "nameofodc.doc",
   }]
}
```

Comment: Of course, everything is possible! What have you tried? What worked? What did not? What did you learn? Which parts of the documentation did you try to follow, and are perhaps unclear? Have you maybe read through [ask]?

Comment: @Geeme, please check the answer if you are still looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the groovy script which can retrieve the `id` from `documents` of the given json response which will then store the value into a test case level custom property called `ID`.

This script is using `static / fixed response` for the demonstration purpose.

```
import groovy.json.*
def response ='''{    "Documents": "1",    "maxResults": "1000",    "pageSize": "1",    "startIndex": "0",    "documents": [   {       "id": "sdfg7234-shdjfh823-wjk283-sdjf29",       "name": "nameofodc.doc",    }] }'''
//Parse the response string
def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
//Extract the value of id and store it at test case level property ID
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('ID', parsed.documents[0].id.toString())
```

If you wants the script to work with dynamic response, replace the 2nd statement of the above with below statement.

```
//Replace LoginRequest with actual test step name
def response = context.expand( '${LoginRequest#Response}' )
```

**How to use the above stored `ID` in other steps?**

- If the next step is Groovy Script

```
context.expand('{#TestCase#ID}')
```

or

```
def id = context.testCase.getPropertyValue('ID')
log.info "ID retrieved from test case property is ${id}"
```

- If the next step is request step, then use [property expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html), say `${#TestCase#ID}`